# How to find USB product id of the iPad Air (For java usage)

Tags: java, ios, ipad

I'm trying to find out what is the model number/product id of the iPad Air.

I already have the numbers of other models, for example:

1. iPhone3:   4759 / 4763 / 4764
2. iPad2:     0x129f / 0x12a2 / 0x12a3
3. iPad3:     4772 / 4779

I don't know where the other guy got them (can't ask him).

Note: I'm connecting an iOS device to my PC and and then running my application on the PC.
I also found [this page](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht5452#ipad5), this is not what I'm looking for.

Java code:

```
public enum ProductID {
    iPhone1_1(4752), iPhone1_2(4754), iPhone2_1(4756), ... , iPad2_3(0x12a3), iPad3_1(4772),
            iPad3_2(4779), iPod5_1(4778), Unknown(-1);
    int id;

    .....

    functions

    .....
    public IOSDevice getDeviceName(){
        switch(this){
        case iPhone1_1:
        case iPhone1_2:
            .....

        default:
            return IOSDevice.iphone;
        }

    }
}
```

**UPDTAE**

I found this [page](http://www.linux-usb.org/usb.ids), it might be helpful to people who search usb ids.

Comment: Java does not run on the iPad Air.

Comment: I'm not running my application on iOS, just connecting an iOS device to my PC.

Comment: Did you get these identifiers from within your Java code? I've never encountered them before.

Comment: No, they are hard coded. I meant that they appear in the Java code but I didn't get them through a function call.

Comment: Completely unclear what you are asking.  Voting to close.